# Jenkins deploy plugin to deploy to multiple hosts on single tomcat

Tags: jenkins, tomcat7, jenkins-plugins

I have various websites hosted on my tomcat. And hence, I've edited server.xml to contain multiple host entries.

The jenkins deploy plugin uses the manager to deploy to the default host, i.e. tomcat/webapps

So how I can deploy each war to a different host/website.

I've already searched it for more than 30 minutes, people keep mentioning about multiple tomcat servers, but none-mentioned about single tomcat instance and multiple hosts.

Hopefully, someone can help me here. May be I missed terms in searching because this seems to be a very common requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a strange email from someone asking me if I'd find the solution of this :

The solution I used is :

`I wrote a post build script, which will delete the war from tomcat deployment folder
and then it'll copy the built war from jenkins to that folder`